# How do i start text str_split after some characters

Tags: php, string, split, character

I have the code:

```
$txt = "lookSTARTfromhereSTARTagainhere";

$disp = str_split($txt, 4); 

for ($b = 0; $b<3; $b++) {
    echo "$disp[$b]"; 
}
```

which return '`look`', '`STAR`' '`Tfor`' in a text line of '`lookSTARTfromhereSTARTagainhere`' my problem is how do i start my text split from '`START`'  example my result output for text line of '`lookSTARTfromhereSTARTagainhere`' after split look like '`from`' '`here`' '`again`' thanks for your time and understanding

Comment: So you don't want START to appear at all right? only look,from here , again here want to appear

Comment: @pr1ce3 just to start the str_split from START e:g 'from' 'here' 'again' to apear only thanks for your impact in my soluction

Comment: is the expected array supposed to be `["from", "here", "again", "here"]`? One word is five letters the others four. How is the code going to know which is which?

Comment: @EniediMonday check my answer. If it helps.

Comment: @EniediMonday If any of the provided solution worked. Please, be sure to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it may not be  possible by str_split as 'again' has 5 characters. you can get  'from', 'here' by following code.

```
$txt = "lookSTARTfromhereSTARTagainhere";
$txt = str_replace('look','',$txt);
$txt = str_replace('START','',$txt);
$disp = str_split($txt, 4); 
for ($b = 0; $b<3; $b++) {
    echo "$disp[$b]"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> how do i start my text split from 'START'

Simply with `explode` and `array_slice` functions:

```
$txt = "lookSTARTfromhereSTARTagainhere";
$result = array_slice(explode('START', $txt), 1);

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => fromhere
    [1] => againhere
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your expected output is four letter words from start you can explode on START then remove first item and use str_split to split each array item to four letter words.

```
$txt = "lookSTARTfromhereSTARTagainhere";

$arr = explode("START", $txt); // Explode on START
unset($arr[0]); // first item is before START, we don't need that.
$res = [];
foreach($arr as $val){
    $temp = str_split($val, 4); // Split array item on four letters.
    $res = array_merge($res, $temp); // merge the new array with result array
}
var_dump($res);
```

https://3v4l.org/3BQ1b

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$txt = "lookSTARTfromhereSTARTagainhere";

$split = explode("START",$txt);
unset($split[0]);

$first_str = str_split($split[1],4);
$t2 = str_split($split[2],5);

$second_str = $t2[0];

array_push($first_str,$second_str);

print_r($first_str);

?>
```

output

> Array ( [0] => from [1] => here [2] => again )