# How do i start str_split just in the middle of characters text line

Tags: php, string, text, split

I have a text line of one million characters and i have PART2 just in the middle of the text line  that is five hundred thusand
s characters before ' PART2 ' and five hundred thusands characters after ' PART2 ' my problem is how do i start str_split from where ' PART2 ' is. In the text line
example

```
 `5_hundred_thusands_text_charactersPART2fivehundredthusandstextcharactersagain`
```

my result output after str_split should start from ' PART2 ' like
'fivehundre',  'dthusandte',  'xtcharacte'
 these my code:

```
 $txt = "5_hundred_thusands_text_charactersPART2fivehundredthusandstextcharactersagain";
   if(preg_match('/(START)/i', $txt))      {
  #start from there
  $see = str_split($txt, 10);
   echo " ','$see"; 
   }
```

my result with this code is just from the starting can i really achieve this in php? Thanks for reading and impact in my soluctions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i start text str\_split after some characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47052931/how-do-i-start-text-str-split-after-some-characters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following solution using [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php):

```
$txt = "5_hundred_thusands_text_charactersPART2fivehundredthusandstextcharactersagain";
$arrParts = preg_split("/PART2/", $txt);

$arrSplitItems = str_split($arrParts[1], 10);
echo implode(',', $arrSplitItems);
```

> **demo:** https://ideone.com/qx0KdS

---

Note: Instead of using [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) you can also use [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
$arrParts = explode('PART2', $txt);
```

Comment: I dont really need my result in array form

Comment: so use `implode`. `str_split` returns an array. see the update

Answer (score 0):

I'd use explode it's actually faster than preg_split, and you're not in need of regex since you know exactly what the delimiter is.

```
$txt = "5_hundred_thusands_text_charactersPART2fivehundredthusandstextcharactersagain";
$r = explode("PART2", $txt);
$see = str_split($r[1], 10);
print_r($see);
```